# Copy/Paste dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, offset, excel-2013

Starting from Sheet "DATA" range `B4:Hx`, where `x` is my last row taking by a row count. I need to copy this range and paste it as values on sheet "bat" starting at `A1`.

Going forward I need to offset columns in `6`. So my second copy will be `I4:Ox` and so one copying appending into `bat` sheet.
I know where I must stop and I'm informing it using the `Funds` value.

**The first error I'm having is when I try set `Column2 = Range("H" & bottomD)` value that is giving me "overflow".**

And sure I don't know yet if my `For` loop would work.

```
Sub Copy_bat()

    Dim bottomD As Integer
    Dim Column1 As Integer
    Dim Column2 As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Funds As Integer

        Funds = Sheets("bat").Range("u3").Value

        Sheets("DATA").Activate
        bottomD = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Column1 = Range("B4")
        Column2 = Range("H" & bottomD)

        For i = 1 To Funds

          Range(Column1 & ":" & Column2).Copy
          Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
          Column1 = Colum1.Range.Offset(ColumnOffset:=6)
          Column2 = Colum2.Range.Offset(ColumnOffset:=6)

        Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What value is under `Range("H" & bottomD)`? Integer values range from `from -2,147,483,648 through 2,147,483,647`. The problem may also be a string instead of a number

Comment: since today my "data" sheet have only info till row 9, so I expect this range to be "H9"  ...I see stopping mouse over variable "bottomD"  that it value "9"

Comment: Not the cell Address. I meant the actual cell H9 value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Always use `Option Explicit` at the beginning of every module to prevent from typos. Always! You had typos at the bottom - `Colum1` and `Colum2`.
2. Avoid `Activate` and `Select` (you had `Sheets("DATA").Activate`) - better performance, smaller error chance. Instead, you should **always explicitly** tell VBA which sheet you are referring to.
3. While pasting values you can simply do something like `Range2.value = Range1.value`. No need to `.Copy` and then `.Paste`.

I did my best to understand what you need. From my understanding you did not use `Range` data type, while you needed that. This caused you errors.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copy_bat()

    Dim bottomD As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Funds As Integer
    Dim rngArea As Range

        Funds = Sheets("bat").Range("u3").Value
        
        With Sheets("Data")
            bottomD = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Set rngArea = Range(.Range("B4"), .Range("H" & bottomD))
        End With
        
        For i = 1 To Funds
          Sheets("bat").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)(2).Resize(rngArea.Rows.Count, rngArea.Columns.Count).Value = _
            rngArea.Value
          Set rngArea = rngArea.Offset(, 7)
        Next

End Sub
```

I made one `rngArea` variable of type `Range` instead of 2 variables (`Column1` and `Column2`). This code takes info from "Data" sheet and puts that to "bat" sheet. Then offsets to right by **7(!)** columns in "Data" sheet and puts data in "bat" sheet **below** the data that was put previously.